# Kendo Grid inline editing not firing event when adding item after pressing update

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

For some reason the update event is not firing when adding item in an inline edit mode in Kendo Grid.  I have been going over the documentation and trying to implement the code as likely as I possibly can.  I´ve also been monitoring firebug and the console never shows any activity.  The [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/editing-inline.html) works well but my code doesn´t.

It works perfectly when editing or deleting item from the grid, but when creating an item nothing works, no activity.  Could the problem possibly be that the GroupID has no Guid declared yet and the grid doesn´t therefore fire the event?  (I´m completely guessing out of thin air, I´m at a loss)

**My razor code:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GroupViewModel>()
  .Name("GroupGrid")
  .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(c => c.GroupID).Hidden();
          columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
          columns.Bound(e => e.FK_CategoryID).EditorTemplateName("CategoriesList").Title("Category").ClientTemplate("#:CatName#");
          columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(170);
      })
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 500px;" })
  .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
  .Scrollable(s => s.Enabled(false))
  .Selectable(s => s.Enabled(true).Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Ajax()
                                .Read(read => read.Action("Group_Grid_Read", "Home"))
                                .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                                .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.GroupID))
                                .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "Home"))
                                .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "Home"))
                                .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "Home"))
  )
  .Events(e => e.Change("onGroupGridChange").Save("GroupGrid_Save"))
)
```

**My controller action:**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult EditingInline_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, GroupViewModel groupViewModel)
{
    if (groupViewModel != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // add group
        // abbreviated
    }

    return Json(new[] { groupViewModel }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

**My ViewModel:**

```
public class GroupViewModel
{
    public Guid GroupID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid? FK_CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CatName { get; set; }
}
```

**### EDITED ###**

I think I have stumbled on something.  I changed the column binding to include all the four columns and not hide them.  When doing that I could populate all the four fields.  After doing that the event finally was fired.

Now I have another question regarding the *GroupID* Guid.  Since I want to keep the *GroupID* and the *CatName* variables hidden, how can I populate the *GroupID* with *"new Guid()"* and the *CatName* with *"new string()"* after clicking the *Add new record button*?

It seems that the problem was lying with the validation of the new record.

```
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.GroupID);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
    columns.Bound(e => e.FK_CategoryID).EditorTemplateName("CategoriesList").ClientTemplate("#:CatName#");
    columns.Bound(c => c.CatName);
    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(170);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the GroupID and CatName hidden and provide the values during Kendo Grid's call to the dataSource..parameterMap.

You can modify the fields of the newly added rows before sending the data to the controller by providing a handler to the dataSource.transport.parameterMap. E.g. :

`$("#GroupGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.transport.parameterMap = function (data, operation) {
        for(var i in data.models) {
            data.models[i].GroupID = new GUID();
            data.models[i].CatName = "Doge";
        }
    };`

Comment: For some reason that doesn´t work, I´m still getting the validation error.  The function for the parameterMap never gets called.